# How do I network movement with photon

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

not for player movement but I need to network the AI's movement

well I haven't really tried anything because idk how to network movement

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use one of three approaches.

### Easy mode

Add PhotonView and SimpleMode2D to your player

```cs
public SimpleMode2D : Monobehaviour {

[SerializeField] private PhotonView view;
[SerializeField] private float speed;

private void Update() {
    if(!view.IsMine) return;
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw(“Horizontal”);
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw(“Vertical”);

    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + (h * speed), transform.position.y + (v * speed));
}
```

### RPCMode

You will still need to add PhotonView and RPCPlayer and to your player, but this time your movement control will be separately

```cs
public class RPCPlayer : Monobehaviour {

[PunRPC]
private void RPCMove(Vector2 newPosition){
transform.position = newPosition;
}

}
```

```cs
public RPCMode2D : Monobehaviour {

[SerializeField] private PhotonView player;
[SerializeField] private float speed;

private void Update() {
    if(!player.IsMine) return;
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw(“Horizontal”);
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw(“Vertical”);
    var position = player.transform.position;
    player.RPC("RPCMove", new Vector2 (position.x + (h * speed), position.y + (v * speed)));
}
```

### RaiseEvent Mode

Here you will need to create player instantiation/deletion and manipulation. I'm using this method because it more flexible but more complex. You can refer to [documentation](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent). Sorry here without code for now, I'll update this comment if you get interested in RaiseEvent usage.